# What is the Time Value of European Options if r=0?

Tags: options, european-options, time

As I understand it, time value for **European** options is as follows:
[image]

What if r=0? Then puts should behave the same as calls, right? Would the time value always be nonnegative or could it be negative?

Comment: So this is closed as off-topic because it's "too basic". What's the answer then?

Comment: I didn't vote to close this but there have been questions asked about this topic here on QFSE. Hint: It depends how you define time value. Most of the time it's defined (eg for a put option) as $P(S_t,K) - (K-S_t)_+$ which can indeed be negative for low values of the current spot price $S_t$ since the no-arbitrage relationship for a put option is $P(S_t, K) \geq (Ke^{-r(T-t)} - S_t e^{-q(T-t)})_+$. So when $S_t$ is very very low and with say quite long time to maturity then you could find yourself in the situation $(K-S_t)_+ > P(S_t,K) \geq (Ke^{-r(T-t)} - S_t e^{-q(T-t)})_+ > 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that. But time value will never be negative for a put when interest is negative, and never negative for a call when interest is positive. I am defining time value as total value minus intrinsic value. Under this definition can time value be negative for puts and calls when r=0?

Comment: See my comment. Look at situations (plug in some numbers/plot)  with/without divs, with/without cost of carry, and with negative and non-negative rates. The important point is how you define time value and the no-arb relationships.